# Get Slider value from three dynamic values Max, Min and Gap iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, dynamic, uislider

I have implemented a slider where the values Max, Min and Gap (decimal value) are dynamic. Now i need to get output satisfying all this three values.

**For eg :-** Min value is 3.0, Max value is 25 and Gap is of 0.3 . So now my output should be like 3.3 , 3.6, 3.9, 4.2 etc where end value should be 25.

Now i am unable to get this math correct for different dynamic values. Any help would be great.!

Comment: i think Gap value increment series cant be end with the exact max value.

Comment: A bit of  difference is ok ..

Comment: @Zck Please provide the code of how you are calculating the series

Comment: @Zck check my below answer

Answer (score 0):

**In Objective C**

I didn't checked objective C code But May be it will help you. Just try it out.

```
float gapValue = 0.3;
float minValue = 3.0;
float maxValue = 25.0;

float currentValue = gapValue; 
NSMutableArray *rangeValues = [NSMutableArray array];

 /* while loop execution */
   while(true)
   {
      currentValue  += gapValue ;
      if currentValue <= maxValue {
          [rangeValues addObject:currentValue];
      }else{
         break;
      }
   }

NSLog(@"%@\n", rangeValues);
```

In Swift:

```
for i in stride(from: 3.0, through: 25.0, by: 0.3) {
    print(i)
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it just gives me(
    "5.5",    6,  "6.5", 7, "7.5", 8, "8.5", 9,  "9.5",  10,  "10.5", 11,  "11.5", 12  "12.5", 13, "13.5" , 14, "14.5", 15,  "15.5", 16, "16.5", 17, "17.5", 18 "18.5"  19,  "19.5",  20, "20.5",  21",   "21.5", 22,  "22.5", 23, "23.5",24,"24.5", 25, "25.5", 26, "26.5",27", "27.5",28,"28.5", 29,"29.5",30)
on first drag than after it return empty.

Comment: Glad to help.if it useful you can upvote & accept it.

Comment: sorry i m not aware of slider processing just debug & check it.What is the min & max value?